# spyder IPython console input() fails

Tags: python, input, console, ipython, spyder

I'm attempting to run a simple while loop with an input() to stop the flow periodically, as shown below:

```
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: while True:
   ...:     print("Hello")
   ...:     x = input("enter a num")
   ...:     if x == 1:
   ...:         print("ok")
   ...:         
Hello

enter a num1
Hello

enter a num1
Hello

enter a num1
```

However, it seems like after a couple passes, I can no longer hit enter and I can't even stop the execution of  the code using a hotkey. Does anyone know if this is an issue with Spyder's IPython console or a local error?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It works fine on Linux, so it's probably a Windows subtle issue.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Is there no apparent solution? It seems like it would be fairly important. Perhaps it is only an issue on my machine?

Comment: It works fine for me on IPython 5.2.2 / Python 3.6.0 / Spyder 3.1.3 / Windows 7 64-bit until I press Ctrl-C, at which point I get what you're describing. What 'hotkey' are you pressing and are you sure you get the problem before that? (In a Python console in Spyder, Ctrl-C then Enter successfully breaks out of the same loop.)

Comment: Tested on Windows, I can't reproduce your error either, sorry.